# Is it possible to send data without selector in Angular?

Tags: angular, data-binding

I would like to send data from child to parent.
However I didn't use child's selector in parent's html code because it is dialog of Angular Material and just use "MatDialogRef" and "dialog.open()"
In this case I couldn't use "EventEmiter". How can I send data when I click on the dialog panel?

Comment: If you didn't use the selector then it's not really a child is it?  If it were a child you could use @ViewChild but I'm not sure that would work in this case.  You might be able to subscribe to the dialogs close event and get what you need from that, but without code it's tough to help.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, your question is very vague and I don't think a lot of people (including myself) can understand your issue. However I am gonna be a prophet and make a guess that you are using `MatDialogue` and want to get some data from it.
You can achieve this in two ways depending on your architecture and how you fire up the dialogue.

1. Pass in the objects of parent as input to the dialogue to be manipulated, thus you have the changes on parent level automatically like the example you can find in this link *https://stackblitz.com/angular/njdkroaomnb?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example-dialog.html*
   OR
2. Use `@Output()` to emit the object and listen to it on parent that implements this dialogue view. In this case you can follow the steps below:

   - Make your modal dialogue component **myModal.component.html** and implement the show function as follows:

```html
<button (click)="onOpenClicked(content)" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%">
Open Modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<ng-template #content let-modalCon let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Create User</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  PPut the body of the modal here
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="closeContent()">
      Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="confirm()">Confirm</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

- On the underlying controller **myModal.component.ts** implement the following necessary functions

```html
constructor(
    config: NgbModalConfig,
    private modalService: NgbModal) {
    // Customize default values of modals used by this component tree
    config.backdrop = 'static';
    config.keyboard = false;
  }
  
  @Output() public confirmEventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  modalReference: any;
  onOpenClicked(content) {
      this.modalReference = this.modalService.open(content, { centered: false });
    }
  confirm() {
  this.confirmEventEmitter.emit('WhateverObjectYouHave');
  this.modalReference.close();
  }
  closeContent() {
  this.modalReference.close();
  }
```

- Then you can use this modal component in another component by importing the corresponding tag to the DOM of the target component and invoking a function when the modal component emits a value like following:
  `<app-myModal (confirmEventEmitter)="onConfirmEventEmmited($event)"></app-myModal>`
  in which `onConfirmEventEmmited(event:any)` is a function in your host's component.ts file.
  I hope this was helpful.